# How to make type variables less rigid?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism

I had been trying to implement automatic differentiation, from this [post](https://www.quora.com/What-are-20-lines-of-code-that-capture-the-essence-of-Haskell-Try-to-follow-standard-Haskell-style-Comments-and-spaces-between-code-do-not-count-as-lines-They-can-also-consist-of-individual-snippets-of-code-but-have-to-add-up-to-20-lines/answer/Tikhon-Jelvis?share=1)

Here is what I had, which worked so far:

```
data DX a = DX { val :: a, dx :: DX a }

instance Num n => Num (DX n) where
  fromInteger x = DX (fromInteger x) 0
  DX x₀ x' + DX y₀ y' = DX (x₀ + y₀) (x' + y')
  DX x₀ x' - DX y₀ y' = DX (x₀ - y₀) (x' - y')
  x@(DX x₀ x') * y@(DX y₀ y') = DX (x₀ * y₀) (x * y' + y * x')
  signum (DX x₀ x') = DX (signum x₀) 0
  abs x@(DX x₀ x') = DX (abs x₀) (signum x * x')

instance Fractional n => Fractional (DX n) where
  fromRational n = DX (fromRational n) 0
  x@(DX x₀ x') / y@(DX y₀ y') =
    DX (x₀ / y₀) ((x' * y - x * y') / y ^ 2)

instance Eq a => Eq (DX a) where
  a == b = val a == val b
instance Ord a => Ord (DX a) where
  compare a b = compare (val a) (val b)
instance Show a => Show (DX a) where
  show (DX x (DX x' (DX x'' _))) = show [x, x', x'']

var x = DX x 1
```

And then, I tried to define Newton's Method, which is where I got stuck:

```
newtons :: (Num a, Fractional a, Ord a) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
newtons eps f guess
  | abs (f guess) < eps   = guess
  | otherwise             = newtons eps f newGuess
    where
      newGuess              = guess - (x₀/x')
      (DX x₀ (DX x' _))     = f (var guess)
```

The error I get is this:

```
randomStuff.hs:75:34:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘DX a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            newtons :: (Num a, Fractional a) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
          at randomStuff.hs:69:12
    Relevant bindings include
      guess :: a (bound at randomStuff.hs:70:15)
      f :: a -> a (bound at randomStuff.hs:70:13)
      eps :: a (bound at randomStuff.hs:70:9)
      newtons :: a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a (bound at randomStuff.hs:70:1)
    In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘(var guess)’
    In the expression: f (var guess)
```

What I understand of the issue is as follows: I have inferred the given function to be of the type `a -> a`, and yet, I am trying to use it in the form `DX a -> DX a`, which it does not permit.

But I should be able to use the same function again somehow because it should work no matter what the type is as long as it is in the typeclass `Num` and `Fractional`.

Is my understanding correct? How do I get around this? Do I need Rank2Types?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what `RankNTypes` is for.

Comment: You could make the signature `(...) => a -> (DX a -> DX a) -> a -> a` if you don't want `RankNTypes`.  But that would permit nonsense like creating a "differentiable function" `\(DX x x') -> DX (x^2) 0`, so I think the `RankNTypes` solution is correct.

Comment: @luqui thanks, but that does not typecheck in my compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following type signature makes it work

```
newtons :: (Num a, Ord a, Fractional a) => a -> (forall b. (Num b, Ord b, Fractional b) => b -> b) -> a -> a
```

And I can run things like:

```
*Main> newtons 0.001 (\x -> x^2 - 2) 2
1.4142156862745099
```

So, yes, one reasonable way to fix it is to use `Rank2Types`